# Existe alguma maneira de alterar um arquivo de uma tag?

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou com um pequeno problema no meu repositório: Um arquivo da tag `1.0.0` e `1.1.0` precisam ser alterados.

No github percebi que não existe aquela opção de editar quando você seleciona uma tag.

Mas existe alguma maneira de driblar isso, pela linha de comando, para alterar um arquivo de uma tag no git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concordo com o que a resposta [@CiganoMorrisonMendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101066/3635) e pra complementar, qualquer problema que houver mesmo que no repositório e que for corrigido posteriormente deve ser lançado em uma nova atualização para que seja seguido corretamente o fluxo da atualização de um software, imagine que alguém já baixou a versão `1.0.0` ou `1.1.0`, então provavelmente se você pude-se editar alguma delas isto iria causar inconsistência para quem já usa a versão especifica.

Pense que cada correção de problema já é uma atualização, sendo assim até problemas mínimos também devem fazer parte do `x.x.x` (`x.x.x.x`), mesmo que o problema seja em um arquivo do repositório.

Conforme o http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/, dado um número de versão `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH` (`x.x.x`), incremente a:

- Versão maior (`MAJOR`): quando fizer mudanças incompatíveis na API.
- Versão menor (`MINOR`): quando adicionar funcionalidades mantendo compatibilidade.
- Versão de correção (`PATCH`): quando corrigir falhas mantendo compatibilidade.

No caso do teu problema é `PATCH`, então se o problema estava em `1.0.0` e em `1.1.0` você deveria criar uma nova tag `1.1.1`.

Comment: Essa explicação  no final fez eu corrigir o versionamento de um repositório meu. Eu estava usando assim : `1.4`, `1.6`, `1.7`

Answer (score 4):

Não. Se tivesse, a função perderia o sentido.

[*Tags* servem para marcar um ponto na história do seu código](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), como por exemplo um lançamento de uma versão estável, e é por isso mesmo que nenhum arquivo pode ser modificado.

Isto não é exclusividade do Git. Outros controles de versão, como o CVS e o SVN possuem a mesma funcionalidade com as mesmas características.